# What should I do when somebody uses my email?

Tags: support, email, unregistered-users

I have two email addresses (or more!), one of which I'm using for Stack Overflow (with my current account), while I am certainly not using the other anywhere on Stack Exchange.

Recently, I've received an automated message from the Stack Exchange team like this one, on the other email address:

> Recently, you answered a question on The Workplace Stack Exchange, but you haven't verified your email address yet.
>
> Click on the following link to verify your email and set a password so that you can log in.
>
> Set Your Password

A few days later I received a similar message saying that I answered a question on the Islam Stack Exchange.

Obviously somebody who used my email address (on purpose or by accident) for their account, is posting answers to some of the Stack Exchange sites.

What should I do in this case? How can I prevent him from using my email address for their account?

Comment: What (domains) do the links link to? (Are you sure it isn't a scam?)

Comment: @Arjan no I'm sure it's from the stackexchange team, it takes you to a registeration page

Comment: @user689: A registration page *where*? What is the URL?

Comment: I *think* this verification email might be related to the unregistered users functionality (you can post with just a username and email, you then have a cookie-only account).

Comment: @MartijnPieters so what shall I do?

Comment: @user689: I think we'll have to wait for a Stack Exchange employee to respond.

Comment: There was a merger of accounts as a result of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216716/i-have-a-sockpuppet-please-delete-merge-it , which can bring along email addresses with it. Is it possible you're getting these for the email address of that other account, or somehow something for that other account is bleeding across?

Comment: @BradLarson no it's yet another account, (I have more than 3 emails). the emails are sent for a different account than the sock-puppet.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: that's of no help to *this* user; this is a new case, it needs its own attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to mention the email address in public, you should use the "contact us" link to explain the problem.  We can try to identify the account and try to sort out what's going on.  Until then, your guess is as good as ours. ;-)